# Graph data structure selection

Tags: planar-graphs, data-structure

I need to implement an algorithm that works on planar graphs and I want to select an appropriate data structure to represent them.

- The vertices are stored in an array, each with an associated pair of coordinates,
- An edge has an associated polyline between its end vertices, with an arbitrary number of intermediate points (possibly none), stored in sequence in an auxiliary array.
- The edges are undirected (if $a\to b$ exists, then $b\to a$ exists),
- The following primitive operations must be supported:

  - adding an edge between two vertices designated by their indexes,
  - enumerating all edges originating from a given vertex (and recursively, all paths from a given vertex),
  - for a given edge, follow the associated polyline until the end vertex.

I am looking for a data structure that is space efficient $O(V + E)$ and avoids data redundancy.

What would you use ? Candidates that I see are *adjacency lists*, *DCEL*, *winged edges*, but I may be missing one. I guess that *quad edges* is overkill.

Comment: See also https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-half-edge-over-winged-edge

Comment: @lhf: thank you, this is relevant.